# selenium pass value from a file

Tags: variables, testing, selenium, automation

i am trying to pass a value to test case from a file.
here i have worked on a small example, created a js file with content,

```
var sch = 'java';    // sch.js and added to ide options - selenium ide extension
```

i have attached my test case and result i got. the variable value is not read by the ide.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i am very new for selenium, any suggestion how to pass values to ide from a file will be very helpful.

Comment: Make your question clear. You want to do `parameterisation`  in Selenium Ide mean why you didn't add a `Selenium IDE` tag? Otherwise you need parameterisation in the RC or WebDriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more command:

`storeEval | sch | sch`

to read variable from you js-file.

Please note, that you need to save your test, restart Selenium IDE and open test again for correct saving of your selenium ide extensions.

This code works:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>sch</td>
    <td>sch</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=gbqfq</td>
    <td>${sch}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium IDE is not really a tool designed to run your testcases. It helps to generate code that you can use to write your testcases, e.g., in a programming language like Java. Of course you can then read parameters from a file using Java.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have tried to use selenium from my netbeans, i was struck in middle. is their any tutorial that would help me to use selenium from netbeans. any helpful links would be a great help.

Comment: Have a look at the [SeleniumHQ website](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). There is a lot of information and code examples of how to use Selenium with various programming langauges, including PHP.